# Bootstrap Dropdown button not opening on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a navbar with buttons using bootstrap but the dropdowns aren't opening on click. I have included the bootstrap CDN link, bootstrap css link, ajax popper link and the jquery link in the code in the right places. I haven't added any external CSS to the navbar buttons. What can be the issue here?

Here is a snippet:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <div class="new-pickup"> <a class="nav-link" id="new-pickup" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"id="add-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                     New Pickup&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="sms-button">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                          &nbsp;SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delivered Status</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log details</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="email-button">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            &nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Deivered Status</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Status</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="call-button">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-flip-horizontal " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                          Call&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                       </a></div>
                    </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

The main.js file has:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown, .btn-group").hover(function(){
        var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
        if(dropdownMenu.is(":visible")){
            dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked if there is any error in console?

Comment: You also need to show what you have written inside your `main.js`. may be there some mistake, which is causing JS to run

Comment: Added the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because you've added another div in there.

Try rearranging your code so that the element with the class .dropdown-toggle is the next item. Rather than div.sms-button

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try below Code:

**Option : 1**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <div class="sms-button" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" >&nbsp;SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delivered Status</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log details</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Option : 2**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Deivered Status</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Status</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navbar-collapse"` to your clickable icon

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    
        <script src="main.js"></script>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
            <!--code changes here-->
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target=".navbar-collapse"></span>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <div class="new-pickup"> <a class="nav-link" id="new-pickup" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"id="add-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                         New Pickup&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></div>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <div class="sms-button">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                              &nbsp;SMS&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delivered Status</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log details</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <div class="email-button">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                &nbsp;Email&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Deivered Status</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Log Status</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <div class="call-button">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-flip-horizontal " aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              Call&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                           </a></div>
                        </li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    
        </nav>
    
    
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```